# Why is my php script being downloaded instead of running?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and PHP, and I'm currently going through the following tutorial.

http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-tutorial.html

Unfortunately, when I click submit, the myform.php file is being downloaded instead of being run. Is there something I'm missing?

```
<?php
 if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit") 
 {
   $varMovie = $_POST['formMovie'];
   $varName = $_POST['formName'];
 }
?>
```

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>

  <body id="main">
  <section id='ex'>
  <form action="myform.php" method="post">
    Which is your favorite movie?
    <input type="text" name="formMovie" maxlength="50" value="<?=$varMovie;?>">

    What is your name?
    <input type="text" name="formName" maxlength="50" value="<?=$varName;?>">

    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</section>
```

test.php

```
?php 
phpinfo(); 
?>
```

Comment: Post some of your code!

Comment: A machine running PHP?

Comment: Give us the file names and what your server setups is (Apache, PHP, WAMP, MAMP, etc)

Comment: Are you running this locally or on a server? PHP needs to be hosted through a web server that supports PHP.

Comment: I am currently running it on a web server. I'm a student delving into PHP, so I'm not sure what server setup I have; but I've been using Apache2 error logs for debugging my Javascript code, so I'm assuming it's Apache?

Comment: I just tried opening this `test.php` in my browser (http://www..../test.php) and it downloaded again. Does that mean the server does not support PHP?

<?php
phpinfo();
?>

Answer (score 1):

You need to run it in an HTTP server with PHP.  I suggest [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) for Windows sytems and [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) for Mac OSX systems.  For Linux search around for LAMP tutorials.

It could also be that your server is not configured to serve PHP files correctly.

Comment: What's the best way to check aside from phpinfo()?

Comment: Check in Apache's configuration file (or ask your hosting provider if PHP is supported). PHP is obviously either not configured correctly, or simply not installed altogether.